# Is there an equivalent to Groovy in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, groovy

What is the closest thing to groovy/java combo in the C# .net world?

If I am writing an app with static and dynamic parts, what's the dynamic part like groovy on the .NET runtime?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/), [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=IronPython), [IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/) are probably the options.

There are other [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_Languages) languages too.

Comment: Yeap... I have just find out. It turns out there's a Ruby.NET also ... :-/

Comment: Of these sounds like Boo is most groovy like in that it's most C# like? Lot like groovy similar to java.
The others like ruby and python on the .net platform are quite different I assume just like they on the java platform, like Jython etc.

Answer (score 2):

Iron Python or any other language targeting [DLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime)..

Comment: Definitely the DLR; IronPython is doing great things, now on version 2

Answer (score 0):

From what little I heard [Boo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_(programming_language)) goes in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Boo, its 100% interop with other CLI-compatible code - code generated dynamically in Boo is used with c#

Answer (score 0):

You can run Groovy in .net with IKVM

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Running+Groovy+on+.NET+2.0+using+IKVM